# Is the question ban too strict?

Tags: discussion, post-ban

**Disclaimer: This is not a whine because I got banned.**

So, as you can guess I got question banned. I understand why the algorithm did that: None of my questions have a positive amount of votes.

However, I don't think they were *BAD* questions, just, that nobody looked at the question and thought "Wow, that's a great question, I gotta upvote it!"

Yep, I had a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33924537/compile-c-code-using-batch-file) that was just a "code for me pls" question.

Yep, I had a suspicious [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36802314/python-itertools-product-start-from-certain) about brute forcing passwords (that I fixed to be more general)

But most of them are actually useful questions, with research that I put into them before, and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35841781/simple-kits-with-bukkit-api) question for example could help a lot of people new to the Bukkit API.

Most of them are OK questions that follow the guidelines, and I don't think a question ban very appropriate there. Just, nobody really appreciated the question. (for a reason.)

So, basically my question is:

Was the post ban (in your opinion) justified?

The question over [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255583/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th) doesn't help me because I have done what I could (at least IMO) to "salvage" my questions.

Comment: `But most of them are actually useful questions` Apparently not, given their score.

Comment: Nah, seems to be too lenient.

Comment: s/strict/lax  far too lax.

Comment: Why do you think this is a useful question on a programming site: [Weird wifi adapters on Windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36791540/weird-wifi-adapters-on-windows).  Asking off-topic question also contributed to your question ban

Comment: Did you delete some prior Meta questions?

Comment: @BSMP nope. (more characters)

Comment: OK, I think I'm confusing you with a different user.

Answer (score 12):

You have *four* questions with a negative score, and none with a positive score, out of ten.  That doesn't sound strict at all.  That's quite a high failure rate, and not having one person to find any one of your ten questions useful is quite a strong indication that you're not providing valuable contributions here.

You don't need more than ten chances to ask a question of value.

Comment: Do you maybe notice a pattern of a certain way in which my questions are bad? (by the way, thanks for the -7 score, people, that helps)

Comment: It's worth noting that downvotes on Meta don't count towards your reputation.

Comment: @sphanley they don't help me understand where I'm wrong either

Comment: @AmitGold They tell you you've not researched the issue properly as there are multiple meta posts by previous people with the same problem as you that you could have read.

Comment: @AmitGold That's not their purpose.  The comments are there to tell you specifically what you've done wrong.  Votes are there to indicate the quality of the post.

Answer (score 8):

You're misrepresenting your problem here. It isn't just that your questions didn't wow people enough to earn upvotes: a question which sits at 0 doesn't do you a significant amount of harm. Your problem is that every time your questions were voted on, they received downvotes. On top of multiple downvoted posts, you have some which are [off-topic (by way of being related to general computing rather than programming)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36791540/weird-wifi-adapters-on-windows) or [too broad to be answerable by others](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36789497/authorizate-to-router-panel-with-python) (and the second of those examples didn't even garner any downvotes!).

I recommend you spend some time rereading the guidelines looking at examples of good and bad questions, so you can better understand why your questions, generally speaking, do not meet the quality standards expected here.